# Sql sorting date how to

Tags: sql, datetime

This is my current table:

```
+---+----------+
| id| date     |
+---+----------+
| 1 |2014-05-05|
+---+----------+
| 2 |2014-05-06|
+---+----------+
| 3 |2014-05-06|
+---+----------+
| 4 |2014-05-07|
+---+----------+
| 5 |2014-05-07|
+---+----------+
| 6 |2014-05-07|
+---+----------+
```

These are the results I'm looking for:

```
+---+----------+
| id| date     |
+---+----------+
| 1 |2014-05-05|
+---+----------+
| 2 |2014-05-06|
+---+----------+
| 4 |2014-05-07|
+---+----------+
```

Comment: Your original table seems to be sorted by date already. What exactly are you trying to get? Records 1, 2, and 4?

Comment: Which Sql please? SqlServer, Oracle, MySql?

Comment: Is this just that, for any particular date, you want to select the row with the lowest `ID` value? If it's not that, please put **some** effort into actually explaining what the rules are that you want to use to select rows?

Comment: I think the op is asking for distinct values, like SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tbl ORDER BY date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), DATE FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY DATE;
```